# Why do "<<" and "+" behave differently with frozen string objects?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

```
irb(main):009:0> a = "good"
=> "good"
irb(main):010:0> a = "good" + "morning"
=> "goodmorning"
irb(main):011:0> a = "good"
=> "good"
irb(main):012:0> a << " morning"
=> "good morning"
```

Till now both the *`concatenation`* operators work fine.

```
irb(main):013:0> a = "good"
=> "good"

irb(main):014:0> a.freeze
=> "good"

irb(main):015:0> a.frozen?
=> true

irb(main):016:0> a << " welcome"
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
    from (irb):16
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'


irb(main):017:0> a = a +  " welcome"
=> "good welcome"
```

But with a *`frozen`* string a difference is clearly visible from `IRB` that `<<` and `+` are not behaving as they are supposed to. Could anyone tell me the reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are doing *exactly* what they're supposed to. `<<` *modifies* the string it is called on, while `+` is closer to `str.dup << arg`. This behavior is the defined, documented standard.

Comment: I am telling about the frozen string. Could you explain the reason?

Comment: @user2060534: The frozen string is fine with having a copy made of itself, just not being modified itself, and a shallow copy doesn't copy attributes like frozen?.

Answer (score 1):

@Linuxios answer is perfect.

But still here I have tried to show that modification with more transparent way:

```
@ubuntu:~$ irb --simple-prompt
>> a = "good"
=> "good"

>> a.freeze
=> "good"

>> a.frozen?
=> true

>> a.object_id
=> 10557720 # holds the reference to the "good" string object.

>> a = a + " morning"
=> "good morning"

>> a.object_id
=> 10415700 # holds the reference to the new string object "good morning". 

>> a.frozen?
=> false

>> ObjectSpace._id2ref(10415700)
=> "good morning"
>> ObjectSpace._id2ref(10557720)
=> "good"
>> ObjectSpace._id2ref(10557720).frozen?
=> true
```

We can conclude that - yes , string "good" is still frozen. Only the thing what happened is `a` referencing the new object "good morning". Only the reference assignment to `a` has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

[`<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) and [`+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-2B) behave differently on ALL string objects, not just frozen ones. One ([`<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3C-3C)) modifies a string, and the other ([`+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-2B)) returns a new string without modifying the original:

With [`<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3C-3C):

```
string1 = "good"
#=> "good"
string2 = string1
#=> "good"
string1 << " morning"
#=> "good morning"
string1
#=> "good morning"
string2
#=> "good morning"
```

With [`+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-2B):

```
string1 = "good"
#=> "good"
string2 = string1
#=> "good"
string1 = string1 + " morning"
#=> "good morning"
string1
#=> "good morning"
string2
#=> "good"
```

[`Object#freeze`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-freeze) is specifically designed to disallow the sort of behavior I demonstrated above with [`<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) (it prevents objects from being modified), so calling [`<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) on a frozen string results in an error.